# How can I pass a parameter out of an on-click function?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am working with bootstrap dataTables. I have editable Cells and so far my code is working very well:

```
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ejbeaty/CellEdit/master/js/dataTables.cellEdit.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
    $('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
        $('#myTable').data('column', table.cell(this).index().columnVisible);
    });
    table.MakeCellsEditable({
        "onUpdate": myCallbackFunction
    });
});


function myCallbackFunction(updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue) {
    var array = updatedRow.data();
    var id = array[0];
    var column = $('#myTable').data('column');
    console.log("The column is: " + column);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update.php",
        data: {
            updatedCell: updatedCell.data(),
            id: id,
            column: column,
        },
        cache: false
    });
}
```

The output in my console is for example: `The column is 1`

I want to add a feature, namely that column 1 and 2 should not be editable, but all others. So I changed my code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
    $('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
        $('#myTable').data('column', table.cell(this).index().columnVisible);
    });
    var column = $('#myTable').data('column');
    console.log("The new column is: " + column);
    if (column !== 1 || column !== 2) {
        table.MakeCellsEditable({
            "onUpdate": myCallbackFunction
        });
    }
}
```

But the parameter is not passed. My output is: `The new column is: undefined`

---

another solution is this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
        var column;
        $('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
            column = $('#myTable').data('column', table.cell(this).index().columnVisible);
        });
        column = $('#myTable').data('column');
        console.log("The new column is: " + column);
        if (column !== 1 || column !== 2) {
            table.MakeCellsEditable({
                "onUpdate": myCallbackFunction
            });
        }
    }
```

But still the output `The new column is: undefined`

Comment: Do you realize that the lines after it DO NOT wait for the click? That is asynchronous type of action.

Comment: @epascarello no I didn't! :( Thank you! I will test to put the condition into the click function

Comment: @epascarello Unfortunately I cannot do that. Then I need to click twice on the cell until I can edit it

Comment: @epascarello But inside the `myCallbackFunction` it is  working and the function is also not waiting for the click

Comment: It is impossible to WAIT for the click! There is no wait() in JavaScript. The code runs. It does not have a clue it needs the data inside the click. Basically you are trying to eat a pizza before you even order it. Only solution is probably to use mousedown instead of click and put the code inside the callback.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying, but why do I get the output `The column is 1` Why can I use the variable inside the `myCallbackFunction` There it is working

Comment: Becuase the code inside the click runs before the click runs. That is how asynchronous programming works..... You just assign a method, it does not sit there and twiddle it thumbs waiting for it to run. It just continues on with the rest of the code. There is no way to just sit there and wait for it. You need to run the code in the callback of the event listener. It needs to run when the user performs the action. So you need to find a way to make it work. My suggestion is to try mousedown instead of click and see if that allows for it to be editable.

Comment: I will check the mousedown solution!

Comment: mousedown works wonderfully great! Thank you for the solution!